# ListView with Custom Cursor Adapter is Empty/Blank

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursoradapter

So I have been trying to get a ListView to display data from a SQLite Database for a few days now, and I still can't find a solution.

the ListView XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/gotoEntry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Entry" />

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

with the row item looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:textSize="15dp"
android:padding="15dp"
android:id="@+id/thetext"
>
</TextView>
```

My cursoradapter looks like:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
private Cursor iCursor;
private Context iContext;
private final LayoutInflater iInflater;


public ItemAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    iInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    iContext=context;
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
TextView itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thetext);

    itemName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db_Setup.KEY_NAME)));
    }
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) throws InflateException {
    final View view = iInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

The cursor is being made with this method:

```
public static Cursor getName() {
    Cursor q = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new
        String[] {db_Setup.KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
q.moveToFirst();

return q;
}
```

and instantiated in the listactivity like so:

```
Cursor cursor = db_Setup.getName();
```

I am trying to do this in my ListActivity to bind the listview to the cursor:

```
ItemAdapter ia = new ItemAdapter(getBaseContext(), cursor);
ia.bindView(findViewById(R.id.thetext), getApplicationContext(), cursor);
```

There are no errors when I run the app... all there is a button from the XML at the top of this post, and blankness (no listView)...
I have entered some values in the SQLite Database already with something like 14 values or so. Why isn't anything showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line is incorrect.  After you create ItemAdapter, simply call ListActivity.setListAdapter(ia).  See [Displaying query results](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#DisplayResults) for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't expect it to be that small of an error! What would the bindView method be for then?

Comment: This method is called internally by the ListView to bind a record.  You don't call it directly.  You actually can optimize your method.  ListView recycles record views.  If the view parameter is not null, you can re-use it, otherwise inflate a new view.  This will make the scrolling smoother.